# How to update the onclick event using Javascript (ensuring it works in IE 6+)

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, dom-events

I have an "anchor tag" as below which gets dynamically generated (so I cannot control the content). I have added the "id" attribute, the actual tag does not contain an id tag, it is just for demonstration purpose so I can use jsfiddle to test any Javascript.

```
<a title="719132 bytes" id="ah" onclick="DispEx(this, event, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments', '0', 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments', '', '1\u002fPMS\u002f_layouts\u002fWordViewer.aspx?id=\u002fPMS\u002my.docx', '', '67', '0', '0', '0x400000300c231061'); return false;"
    href="/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=/documents/my.docx"
    jQuery16206020211467509253="188">
```

So when someone clicks on a document, there is a security warning that pops up, in order to suppress this warning sign, "the first instance of SharePoint has to be replaced with SharePoint.OpenDocuments.3" and the second instance has to be replaced with an empty string ''

I have managed to update the text with no problem, I have an issue updating the a tag with the new changed tag. basically how do I update the `onclick` event with the text?

Here is what I have done so far (the example can be access here: http://jsfiddle.net/yhUu6/2/)

Basically I am expecting the result to look like this

```
<a title="719132 bytes" id="ah" onclick="DispEx(this, event, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments.3', '0', '', '', '1\u002fPMS\u002f_layouts\u002fWordViewer.aspx?id=\u002fPMS\u002my.docx', '', '67', '0', '0', '0x400000300c231061'); return false;"
    href="/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=/documents/my.docx"
    jQuery16206020211467509253="188">
```

How do I update the `onclick` event of the "anchor tag"?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you opting the complex way? They are just two arguments of a function. Modify their values by using two variables as arguments like this example:

```
<input type='button' value="your anchor" onclick="YourFuntion(arg1,arg2);return false;"/>
<input type='button' value='Try it' onclick='myfunction()'/>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
var arg1 = 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments', arg2='SharePoint.OpenDocuments';
function YourFuntion(a,b)
{
alert(a);
alert(b);
}
function myfunction()
{
 arg1 = 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments.3';
 arg2 = " ";
}
//-->
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Thank so very much for your help. Apologies for not providing the complete information. The anchor tag is dynamically generated and I cannot control this. This is automatically generated by SharePoint, so keeping this in mind how would you alter the onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most optimal solution, but hopefully it could show a JQuery alternative concept. You can remove the complexity of keeping track / managing text parameters from anchor tags and shift it to JQuery (javascript).

The Click event in JQuery:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    $('#ah').bind('click', function() {

        var sharePoint = $(this).attr('parm-data');
        var sharePointParm1 = '';
        var sharePointParm2 = '';

        if("SharePoint.OpenDocuments" == sharePoint) {
            sharePointParm1 = 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments.3';
            $(this).attr('parm-data') = 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments.3';
        } else {
            sharePointParm1 = 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments';
            sharePointParm2 = sharePointParm1;
            $(this).attr('parm-data') = sharePointParm1;
        }

        DispEx(this, event, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'FALSE', sharePointParm1, '0', sharePointParm2, '', '1\u002fPMS\u002f_layouts\u002fWordViewer.aspx?id=\u002fPMS\u002my.docx', '', '67', '0', '0', '0x400000300c231061'); 
        return false;"
    });
</script>
```

And then the altered anchor tag:

```
<a title="719132 bytes" id="ah" parm-data="SharePoint.OpenDocuments"
        href="/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=/documents/my.docx"
        jQuery16206020211467509253="188">
```

Comment: Thank so very much for your help. Apologies for not providing the complete information. The anchor tag is dynamically generated and I cannot control this. This is automatically generated by SharePoint, so keeping this in mind how would you alter the onclick event.

Comment: Well, if your JQuery is below 1.7 you can use [.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or alternatively [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for 1.7 and higher.
This should allow the click event to fire for dynamically generated links.